# How to implement wrapper for lambda with capture?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

`std::function` can wrap lambdas with capture list but how `std::function` implemented? We don't know what is the type of it, it can be assigned to `void*` but then it is not possible to call lambda

Comment: Have you looked at implementations in libstdc++ and libc++?

Comment: @StephenNewell that libraries are just a big mess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: this is incomplete, possibly incorrect and doesn't follow `std::function` api and conventions (e.g. it is not copyable). This is just an example to show one way of how the type erasure of a `std::function` like type can be implemented, striped down to the bare minimum to understand the type erasure technique.

In order to store any type and be able to call it according to a function signature we use polymorphism.

This is the base abstract class for a `Signature` that defines the calling API. `Signature` must be a function type:

```
template <class Signature> struct CallableBase;

template <class R, class... Args>
struct CallableBase<R(Args...)>
{
    virtual R call(Args... args) = 0;
};
```

Next we need a derived class that holds the actual callable object `F` and can call it:

```
template <class F, class Signature> struct Callable;

template <class F, class R, class... Args>
struct Callable<F, R(Args...)> : CallableBase<R(Args...)>
{
    F f;

    Callable(F f) : f{f} {}

    R call(Args... args) override
    {
        return f(args...);
    }
};
```

In our `Function` class we hold a pointer of type `CallableBase` to an object of type `Callable<F>` to enable polymorphism and get the desired behavior:

```
template <class Signature> struct Func;

template <class R, class... Args>
struct Func<R(Args...)>
{
    using Signature = R(Args...);

    std::unique_ptr<CallableBase<Signature>> callable_;

    template <class F>
    Func(F f) : callable_{std::make_unique<Callable<F, Signature>>(f)} {}

    R operator()(Args... args)
    {
        return callable_->call(args...);
    }
};
```

And this gets us a basic type erased `Function`:

```
auto test()
{
    int x = 10;

    Func<int(int, int)> f = [=] (int a, int b) { return a * x + b; };

    return f(2, 5); // 25
}
```